# Did the Martians destroy a planet?

Tags: mars, stranger-in-a-strange-land

In Robert Heinlein's *Stranger in a Strange Land*, do the Martians destroy a planet in orbit between Mars and Jupiter creating the asteroid belt?

I seem to remember there being an implicit threat to Earth because of this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, they destroyed the fifth planet in the solar system.

> *The question was of greater interest because it had not been abstract
>   art, but religious (in the Terran sense) and strongly emotional: it
>   described the contact between the Martian Race and the people of the
>   fifth planet, an event that had happened long ago but which was alive
>   and important to Martians in the sense in which one death by
>   crucifixion remained alive and important to humans after two Terran
>   millennia. **The Martian Race had encountered the people of the fifth
>   planet, grokked them completely, and in due course had taken action;
>   the asteroid ruins were all that remained, save that the Martians
>   continued to cherish and praise the people they had destroyed.** This
>   new work of art was one of many attempts to grok all parts of the
>   whole beautiful experience in all its complexity in one opus. But
>   before it could be judged it was necessary to grok how to judge it.*
>
> *It was a very pretty problem.*

The threat wasn't *implicit*, it was very very *explicit*.

> *Mike looked very sober. “Jubal, listen to a story. Listen all the way through.” **Mike told him of the destruction of the missing Fifth Planet of Sol, whose ruins are the asteroids.** “Well, Jubal?”
>
>   “It reminds me a little of the myths about the Flood.”
>
>   “No, Jubal. The Flood you aren’t sure about. Are you sure about the destruction of Pompeii and Herculaneum?”
>
>   “Oh, yes. Those are established historical facts.”
>
>   “Jubal, the destruction of the Fifth Planet by the Old Ones is as historically certain as that eruption of Vesuvius—and it is recorded in much greater detail. No myth. Fact.”
>
>   “Uh, stipulate it as such. Do I understand that **you fear that the Old Ones of Mars will decide to give this planet the same treatment? Will you forgive me if I say that is a bit hard for me to swallow?”***