# Sci fi novel about a civilisation on a planet between Mars and Jupiter and how it destroyed forming the asteroid belt

Tags: story-identification, books

A long time ago when I was about 10, I read a book (translated to my language) about a civilization on a planet between Mars and Jupiter. I only remember a couple of things from the book but I remember I really liked it.

I remember some names on some characters but I think the translator has changed (translated) the names too. I remember one main character's name is "Maadha", (not sure it's the name on the original book). I also remember characters usually named after planets like Venus, Jupiter, etc. (these names are also translated, so I don't know these names are in the original book).

I remember there is a character with a Hunchback (Like in Notre Dame :-) ), which is actually a nuclear device/bomb, and he is the person who destroyed the planet. Then the main characters are (some couple/lovers) sent to Earth as their planet becomes the asteroid belt. That's the only part I remember correctly.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! You say you read the book "when you were 10" and in your native language, but we don't know when you were 10 or what your native language is. Can you edit those details into the question? They'll help us narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: I read it in the early 90s in Sinhala (Sri Lankan) language. Based on how it was written it should be an old book, with 60s, 70s Sci-fi style.

Comment: Ok found it, It's `The Destruction of Faena`, Thanks @demp. I'm ordering a copy right now. Now I remember the Translated name of the book. It's in Sinhala and the literal translation is 'Destruction of a planet'

Comment: Incidentally "Stranger in a Strange Land" has a very similar thing. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/153022/did-the-martians-destroy-a-planet

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"[The Destruction of Faena](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?301782)" by Alexander Kazantsev. The plot included a hunchback with implanted nuclear device. The book featured a planet Faena which was destroyed by its inhabitants in a nuclear catastrophe, and debris forming an asteroid belt.
It is a first book in an amazing sci-fi trilogy called "Faety" (Faets - as in the name of the inhabitants of Faena planet, or Faety (Фаэты in Russian - original language of the book)), published in 70s.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm ordering a copy right now.